# PIC24 Evaluation Board always returns 1 when reading input from pins [resolved]

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I am trying to set up a function which will read digital input from pins on a PIC24 MCU and use the bits that are read to reconstruct a full value. The MCU can properly receive and send values over UART and output these to a parallel bus, but now I am trying to read into the bus and the pins will always read 1 regardless of whether or not a voltage is present at the pins. I cannot figure out why this is and would appreciate some help if anyone has any insight. These are the functions I am using:

```
void configureReadPins()
{
//configuring pins for bus
TRISAbits.TRISA9 = 1; //configure A9 as input
TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 1; //configure C3 as input
TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1; //configure C4 as input
TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 1; //configure C5 as input
TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 1; //configure B5 as input
TRISBbits.TRISB6 = 1; //configure B6 as input
TRISBbits.TRISB7 = 1; //configure B7 as input
TRISBbits.TRISB8 = 1; //configure B8 as input

//Setting Read pin to output and Write pin to input
TRISBbits.TRISB12 = 0;
TRISBbits.TRISB13 = 1;
}

void readFromFPGA()
{
configureReadPins();

int i = 0;
int bitcount = 0;
int pin = 0;
int index = 0;
uint16_t addressRead = 0;
uint16_t sampleRead = 0;
 
uint16_t comparisonSample = 0;
//LATBbits.LATB12 = 1; //tell FPGA MCU is ready to read
 
//while(PORTAbits.RA1 != 1); //wait for FPGA to set clock pin high in order to start reading the contents of the bus
 
while (index < 1024 && (numSamples != readCounter))
{
    comparisonSample = dataArray1[index];
                   
    //reading sample point
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (bitcount = 0; bitcount < 8; bitcount++)
        {   
            switch (bitcount)
            {
                case 7:
                    pin = PORTAbits.RA9;
                    sampleRead += pin;
                    break;
                        
                case 6:
                    pin = PORTCbits.RC3;
                    sampleRead += pin;
                    break;
                    
                case 5:
                    pin = PORTCbits.RC4;
                    sampleRead += pin;
                    break;
                    
                case 4:
                    pin = PORTCbits.RC5;
                    sampleRead += pin;                       
                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                    pin = PORTBbits.RB5;
                    sampleRead += pin;
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    pin = PORTBbits.RB6;
                    sampleRead += pin;
                    break;
                    
                case 1:
                    pin = PORTBbits.RB7;
                    sampleRead += pin;                        
                    break;           

                case 0:
                    pin = PORTBbits.RB8;
                    sampleRead += PORTBbits.RB8;                        
                    break;  
                        
            }
            //reads in value from left to right in bits
            //AKA case 0 will read RB8, which gives MSB value of 8 bits received
            if (i == 0 || (i == 1 && bitcount != 7) )
                sampleRead <<= 1; //shift next bit to left to get in proper place
            
            pin = 0;
        }
    }
    
    sampleRead = 0;
    index++;
}
```

In all cases, the values of pin is set to 1 after reading from the MCU's pins. Any idea why this is happening?

edit: The problem was I left the pins floating. Since they weren't connected to ground, the transistors used for the pins kept the previous high voltage so the pins were not reading as expected. Once the pins expected to read 0 were connected to ground they read the expected value of 0.

Comment: It's the hardware equivalent of uninitialized variables.

Comment: Don't edit your question to make an answer. You could answer your own question and accept it.